# bluetoothGatt can't connect with target - Unhandled exception in callback

Tags: android, bluetooth, gatt

I tried to connect with my target device using Bluetooth GATT service,
I got this message in console and can't connect.

I tried to connect by using this,

```
bluetoothGatt = mDiscoverderDevice.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);

D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 5D:BB:1E:F0:09:05, auto: true
 D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
 D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=b6173656-60d1-494d-bac2-dc1f1a12f294
 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
 D/ALERT **** :: connectwithGATTServiceandroid.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@20128b49
 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=5D:BB:1E:F0:09:05
 W/BluetoothGatt: Unhandled exception in callback
 W/BluetoothGatt: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6462)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:897)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6880)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4063)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3921)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3896)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at tel.android.com.rseremote.MainActivity.setStatus(MainActivity.java:293)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at tel.android.com.rseremote.MainActivity.access$500(MainActivity.java:37)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at tel.android.com.rseremote.MainActivity$5.onConnectionStateChange(MainActivity.java:381)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onClientConnectionState(BluetoothGatt.java:181)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:70)
 W/BluetoothGatt:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not related to BLE.
you are trying to update a view element like Toast or a TexetView from outside thread.
thats why it says
            `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`

Try using [runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) Method to update the UI Views.